# Object not set to a reference

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

This issue drives me insane, as I can't see what's causing it. The behavior is unexpected and I just can't see how it can occur. When I execute my plugin using the code below, I get the error message "*bada boom*". Just as expected.

```
public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
  throw new Exception("bada boom");
  try
  {
    throw new Exception("bada bing");
    ...
  } catch (Exception) { }
  ...
}
```

However, when I comment out the first throw, I don't get to see "*bada bing*". Instead, I get "*object not set to a reference*"! What the duck?! (Typo intended.)

```
public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
  //throw new Exception("bada boom");
  try
  {
    throw new Exception("bada bing");
    ...
  } catch (Exception) { }
  ...
}
```

Here's graphics for the issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a catch block?

Comment: I guess you have some finally or catch clause that causes `NullReferenceException`. Also post stack trace and SSCCE if possible

Comment: Can we see your cath/finally block?

Comment: `Object not set to a reference` has no meaning. Be clear in your posts.

Comment: Please see the edit. No *finally* in my code. And the *catch* is left empty...   :(

Comment: @HamletHakobyan That's the error message I'm receiving. It's got the meaning equivalent to "*null pointer exception*" or whatever wording your favorite language/platform barks out.   :)

Comment: You cant set the object to reference. Usually we set the reference to the object.

Comment: Please see the edit. That's the exact message. I might have abbreviated it as people generally know which one it is. Or, so I thought, hehe. Sorry if it caused confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example the exception is handled at the caller level and up till a catch block is found. In the second example the exception is handled in the mandatory catch or finally block associated with the try of the Execute method.
So in the code inside that catch or finally block you have a null reference exception

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Execute();
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In main: " + x.Message);
    }

}

public void Execute()
{
  // Goes to the catch block in main
  //throw new Exception("bada boom");

  try
  {
      // Goes to the catch block associated with this try
      throw new Exception("bada bing");
  }
  catch(Exception x)
  {
      // Uncomment this to see the null reference exception in main
      // Console.WriteLine("In Execute: " + x.InnerException.Message);
      Console.WriteLine("In Execute:" + x.Message);
  }
}
```

Well, of course, when I say *mandatory* I want to say that you cant write

```
try
{
   ....
}
```

without a catch or a finally clause following the try. And you can write a catch or finally block without code, but you can't omit one of the two keywords and its block

Comment: *handled in the mandatory catch block* ? catch is not mandatory! it can be finally also.

Comment: catch or finally should be defined (empty if you want, but defined)

Comment: I've got a catch. I just decided to denote it as "...", as it's not compilable to omit it. It's empty, however. Or rather - as good as empty. So I thought. Some idiot (i.e. the forgetful me) has moved a declaration to a later stage in the code, hence the issue. Good eyes.